# CSS to hide Attribute Content

Tags: css

### Expected Result

I want to hide the content of data-count-green if the content is 0.

I have tried using the following

---

#### CSS

```
.myclass[data-count][content='0'] {
  display: none;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .myclass[data-count] {
        position: relative;
      }

      .myclass[data-count][content='0'] {
        display: none;
      } 

      .myclass[data-count]:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: attr(data-count);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <i class='myclass' id="comment" data-count='0' </i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it would just be `.far[data-count-green='0']`, no?

Comment: Also your HTML is malformed in your example, which could be contributing to your issues: `<i class='far' id="comment" data-count-green='0' </i>`

Comment: Your `<i>` has mistakes, didn't properly close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `.far[data-count-green='0']`

```css
.far[data-count-green='0'] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
     <i class='far' id="comment" data-count-green='0'>I'm not visible</i>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I am so thankful to you. I have been trying this for so long.